# Cambiar lugar en datatable search por fila

Tags: datatables

Tengo un datatable y los filtros por columna funcionan, pero quiero colocarlo en la parte de arriba, no abajo.

¿Cómo cambiaría esto?

Tengo este código:

```
 initComplete: function () {
        this.api()
        .columns()
        .every(function () {
            let column = this;
            let title = column.footer().textContent;

            // Create input element


            let input = document.createElement('input');

            //let input = document.createElement('input');
            input.placeholder = title;
            column.footer().replaceChildren(input);

            // Event listener for user input
            input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                    column.search(input.value).draw();
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: explicate mejor por que yo veo los filtros arriba, o te refieres a los input que se ven alli?

Comment: ¿Los _filtros_ que mencionás son los campos que encerraste en amarillo o los títulos de las columnas que están arriba?

Answer (score 0):

algo asi?

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#miTabla').DataTable();

        // Agregar inputs dinámicamente en el encabezado
        $('#miTabla thead th').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html(title + '<br><input type="text" placeholder="Filtrar">');
        });

        // Agregar la funcionalidad de búsqueda por columna
        table.columns().every(function() {
            var that = this;

            $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function() {
                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


<table id="miTabla" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Editar</th>
            <th>Activar</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Clave</th>
            <th>Fecha Creación</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Datos ficticios -->
        <tr>
            <td>Editar1</td>
            <td>Activar1</td>
            <td>Nombre1</td>
            <td>Clave1</td>
            <td>2023-10-01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Editar2</td>
            <td>Activar2</td>
            <td>Nombre2</td>
            <td>Clave2</td>
            <td>2023-10-02</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Agrega más filas aquí con datos ficticios -->
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```